# Paypal integration link

Tags: paypal, hyperlink

I'm using this library to make payment using paypal:
Library: https://github.com/jersonandyworks/Paypal-Library-by-RomyBlack/blob/907e4f16f604fee21395c87b6d08e4b832f1cfd7/Paypal_lib

But i would like to know how can a add the shipping cost to show in paypal.

my link to redirect to paypal like this:

https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?business=dodiatheke%40hotmail.com&cmd=_cart&production=0&custom=&invoice=58003497&upload=1&currency_code=BRL&disp_tot=Y&cpp_header_image=&cpp_cart_border_color=000&no_note=1&return=http%3A%2F%2Fshop41.co%2Fpayments%2Fnotify_payment&cancel_return=http%3A%2F%2Fshop41.co%2F&notify_url=process_payment.php&rm=2&lc=EN&shipping=&shipping2=&handling=&tax=&discount_amount_cart=&discount_rate_cart=&first_name=&last_name=&address1=&address2=&city=&state=&zip=&email=&night_phone_a=&night_phone_b=&night_phone_c=&item_name_1=250+PARES+DE+TIRAS+PARA+FABRICAR+CHINELOS.&amount_1=197.50&quantity_1=11&item_number_1=3002&item_name_2=CHINELO+ANGEL+PINK&amount_2=14.90&quantity_2=20&item_number_2=20001

but if i put the price in the shipping nothing appears on the paypal.

I dont know how to include the price.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it appears that you are using PayPal Standard and not Express Checkout, here is one way you can have PayPal calculate all shipping costs automatically. 
This is from the PayPal Documentation:
You can customize your PayPal Payments Standard shipping rates based on currency, region, shipping method, and delivery time. Or you can base your shipping rates on fixed amounts or fixed percentages.

Here's how to calculate shipping costs for purchases made on your website:

1. Log in to your PayPal account.
2. Click Profile.
3. Click My selling tools.
4. Under "Shipping my items," click Update near "Shipping calculations."
5. Click Start under "Set Up Domestic Shipping Methods" or "Set Up International Shipping Methods." If you've already set up shipping methods, you can click Add new shipping method or Add another shipping method.
6. Select the currency and regions, and then click Continue.
7. Specify your preferences for shipping method, delivery time, and shipping rate, and then click Continue.
8. Review your selections, and then click Save Shipping Methods.

To enable your shipping calculations, you must click Use settings saved in your PayPal profile within each button you have created. To offer free shipping, select "Use specific amount," and enter 0.00 as the amount. The HTML code in your shopping cart buttons under "Shipping" overrides the shipping methods in your Profile.

If you calculate costs by weight, you must enter the weight of each item within each "Buy Now" or "Add to Cart" buttons you create.

If you need more specific shipping calculation options, go to our developer network at https://developer.paypal.com or contact your developer.

Comment: Thank's for reply,

but my shipping cost come from my cart, if i set cost in paypal page i think it's not work for me.